# UWP ToggleSwitch put Content on the Left

Tags: xaml, uwp

Is there an easy way to get the content (text) on the left side of a ToggleSwitch control?  (Else than messing up the Template).

Thanks

Comment: Good question, not the first time I have been asked this. There is no built-in way to handle this other than "messing up the control template" or, which might be easier, handle it with external `TextBlocks`.

Comment: I ended up modifying the template, wasn’t that bad.  But I like the idea of using an external textblock.  Thanks for that « out of the box » thinking :)

Answer (score 3):

You should alter the template if you want to do it correctly.

However, if you want to fix it in a hacky way, change the `FlowDirection` of the control. But then you'll have to tweak with margins and alignments to make it look decent when used with other controls (see image below for default alignment).

```
<StackPanel>
    <ToggleSwitch OffContent="Test" OnContent="Test2"></ToggleSwitch>
    <ToggleSwitch OffContent="Test" OnContent="Test2" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"></ToggleSwitch>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: Flowdirection changed]

Comment: That's why I started with "you should alter the template" :)

Comment: Not bad... its clever but, I’m a perfectionist, so I guess I’ll modify the template then ;)

Comment: Happy you've "seen the light" ;) Changing a template seems scary at first, but it is quite often the best solution.

Comment: can you publish the altered template for us, please? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A modified template displaying SwitchToggle content on the left [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/RafiHenig/c147023bf2d18d093fe2b842ba05c867).